# Eclipse gdb Debug exit with "No source available for.." but the program works properly

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I'm debuggin a program that in `run mode` works correctly doing what it has been programmed to do.
I've a method:

```
int aeswrapper::EncryptToFile(string Message, string FileName)
{
    ofstream file;
    file.open(FileName, ios::binary | ios::out);

    if (file.good())
    {
        // Convert the Message in an array of uint8_t
        uint8_t *_msg = (uint8_t*) Message.c_str();

        int len = Message.length();

        uint8_t *input;

        int rlen = this->pad(_msg, len, &input);

        uint8_t *output = new uint8_t[rlen];

        AES128_CBC_encrypt_buffer(output, _msg, rlen, key, iv);

        file.write((char*)output, rlen);

        file.close();

        return rlen;
    }
    else
    {
        Error("aeswrapper::EncryptToFile -> Qualcosa è andato storto con l'apertura del file!");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It works. Into the `main` the call to the member is present:

```
int main() {

    aeswrapper aes;

    string Message = "username=test&password=test";

    int len = aes.EncryptToFile(Message, "text.bin");

    cout << "Length: " << len << endl;

    [...]


    return 0;
}
```

When in `Debug` I try to `Step into` the `ase.EncryptToFile` method, the Debug stop functioning with the error I captured through the following image:

[image]

Furter details: I use Eclipse with MinGW-64bit GCC Compiler (under MSYS64) and GDB.

What's the problem?

Thank's to everyone!

Comment: Usually this means that a file or library was compiled with no symbols.  If you want the symbols, you may have to rebuild with the "-g" option.

Comment: Yeah you get this with Java in eclipse too, that'll be right

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yeah! I changed the Debugging level (`Project Properties -> Build -> C/C++ Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Debugging -> Debug Level`) from `Maximum (-g3)` to `Default(-g)` and now it enters the function! Thank's so much! Just for info, what's the specific reason for this problem? What type of symbols the compiler wasn't generating so the debugging of the function wasn't possible?

Comment: Symbols means things like function names and variable names.

Comment: EDIT: The issue persists! Now I'm able to enter the function; however the debug crashes on the `return` istruction and the environment is not able to return to the main procedure. Some help?